# Simplification of iterating

Tags: python, iterator

```
str = ''

for i in self.obj:
    str += '[' + self.obj[i] + ']';
```

Is there a way to simplify the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `self.obj` is a dict:

```py
string = ''.join('[%s]' % x for x in self.obj.itervalues())
```

If it's a custom object implementing `__getitem__` instead:

```py
string = ''.join('[%s]' % self.obj[x] for x in self.obj)
```

Note that I don't use `str` as a variable name. *You shouldn't do this as well*, because it's a builtin function in Python.

**UPDATE:** Regarding your last comment, you could do something like this:

```py
string = ''.join('[%s%s]' % (x[1:], self.obj[x]) for x in self.obj)
```

Or if you prefer the (more Pythonic?) `format` method:

```py
string = ''.join('[{0}{1}]'.format(x[1:], self.obj[x]) for x in self.obj)
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Sooo, what's wrong? OP uses `obj[i]` where `i` is the index, so he is iterating over the values as well?

Comment: @Johan: Please see my comment above.

Comment: I suspect that he was looking at my answer, which I deleted as soon as I realized. :-)  We should probably discourage the OP from using "str" as a variable name, though.

Comment: @Niklas Baumstark, More thanks!. Please tell, but what if we extend the expression like this: `'[' + i[1:] + self.obj[i] + ']'`

Comment: @tomas: I added a suggestion for this as well.